# How do I write a service to correct spellings in my entities using API.ai Dialogflow?

Tags: bots, botframework, dialogflow-es

I searched [api.ai] and [dialogflow] tags thoroughly before asking this question.
I query an API to get me a json array every 20 seconds, Below snippet shows a few objects from the array

```
{
"id": "pivx", 
"name": "PIVX", 
"symbol": "PIVX", 
"rank": "46", 
"price_usd": "8.65711", 
"price_btc": "0.00052161", 
"24h_volume_usd": "7948150.0", 
"market_cap_usd": "477700707.0", 
"available_supply": "55180159.0", 
"total_supply": "55180159.0", 
"max_supply": null, 
"percent_change_1h": "0.07", 
"percent_change_24h": "21.92", 
"percent_change_7d": "69.6", 
"last_updated": "1513821853", 
"price_eur": "7.2916846395", 
"24h_volume_eur": "6694543.93755", 
"market_cap_eur": "402356318.0"
}
```

I have a bot where the person often types something like "PIVY to USD" how do I correct "PIVY" as "PIVX" I had a few approaches in mind

1. I tokenize "PIVY to USD" giving me "PIVY", "to" and "USD" , I eliminate stop words and am left with "PIVY" and "USD" I take each word and compare it with all the symbols in the array to get the set of candidates with the lowest levenshein score. Does this approach make sense?
2. If I run "PIVY to USD" on API.ai, I only get USD since PIVY is a misspelling of the entity PIVX
3. I also have other intents so if the person types "How are you" I dont want to tokenize and search each word in here with all the symbols in my array

How do I correct spelling mistakes for a particular intent? One approach is to have 2 intents 1) that detects the existence of currencies before correcting spelling mistakes and 2) that actually converts them?  I am using the Bot framework

Kindly give your suggestions on this. Thank you for your time to read this long question

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you can follow in your query:
1) Intent based solution if your use case is only to convert PIVX to USD.
2) If you are converting more then one conversions then you need to create a dictionary and check the conversation in key value pair to avoid error. (Not every time only in case of getting the intent of conversion and PIVY in your phrase)

i hope this will help you.
do let me know in case you require more help.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) super appreciated
1) my case is not limited to pivx alone as i am converting from anything to anything
lets talk about 2) i did not follow you , i already have a json with all the symbols on it, the user types PIVY to USD, what do we do here? fuzzy match every word? eliminate stop words? once i spell check and get the proper entity value PIVX, i can always send this to api,ai and it ll do its magic